# How to rotate a canvas by following mouse if the canvas already has something drawn on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I currently have a canvas that has an element drawn on it that I draw using a custom function and the onload function I would like to know how to be able to rotate this canvas around by following the mouse 360 degrees like turning a wheel. The code is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Help</title>   
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <canvas id="MyCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById("MyCanvas").getContext("2d");
                ctx.translate(250,250);
            function draw(){  
                ctx.arc(0,0,100,0,Math.PI*2,false);  // x, y, radius, start angle, end angle, false/true  
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(-100,0);
                ctx.lineTo(100,0);
                ctx.moveTo(100,0);
                ctx.lineTo(60,-80);
                ctx.moveTo(60,-80);
                ctx.lineTo(-100,0);
                ctx.stroke();
            } 
            window.onload=draw;
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how this would be possible I have tried multiple different functions. however, they do not seem to be able to do anything. 
help will be very appreciated.

Edited but with slight issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Help</title>   
    </head>
    
    <style>
    canvas{
         border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    
    <body>
       
        <canvas id="Canvas" height="300"></canvas>
        
        <script>
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            
            const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
            function mouseEvents(e) {
              const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
              mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
              mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
            }
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);

            
            function drawRotated(x, y, angle) {
              ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
              ctx.rotate(angle);
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
              ctx.moveTo(-100, 0);
              ctx.lineTo(100, 0);
              ctx.lineTo(60, -80);
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            
            function update(timer) {
              ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

              
              var angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - 150, mouse.x - 150);

              
              drawRotated(150, 150, angle);
              requestAnimationFrame(update);
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors or problems are you running into?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate the existing content of HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517879/how-to-rotate-the-existing-content-of-html5-canvas)

Comment: I tried setting just simple things like loops to rotate the canvas on click and so on but it seems that the onclick was not registering as it did not do anything when I tried.

Comment: @JohnEllmore I have also tried saving it as an image then rotating but it also did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a mouse move listener, and an animation loop.

In the animation loop get the mouse position and use `Math.atan2(` to get the direction from the center canvas to the mouse.

Then set the transform with `ctx.setTransform` to scale and position the designs rotation center, and then use ctx.rotate to rotate the transform to point along the angle computed.

See snippet for more details

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// create mouse event listener
const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
function mouseEvents(e) {
  const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);

// draw design at x,y and rotated by angle
function drawRotated(x, y, angle) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.moveTo(-100, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(60, -80);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// render loop called 60 times a second
function update(timer) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

  // get angle from center to mouse
  var angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - 150, mouse.x - 150);

  // draw rotated design
  drawRotated(150, 150, angle);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but just one question. It seems that when I try to implement the code that I get the canvas with borders but nothing inside.

Comment: I have added what I've done as a snippet, can you please tell me what the issue with my implementation of the code is ?

Comment: Nevermind it turns out it was just my naming of the class. Thank you very much again.